# SharePoint Online calendar change display form to custom form in Pages library without using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, tasks, task-list

Within Sharepoint online, I have a Task list type that is displayed on a calendar according to the due date.

When I hover over the entries in the calendar the link relates to the default Display form (DispForm.aspx). What I would like to do is change the display form to a custom form that I have in ~sitecollection/Pages/TaskDisplayForm.aspx

The obvious thing is to go into the Sharepoint designer for the Task list, however, I cannot see a way I can point the default display form to a pre-existing page I can only create new pages.

I tried in Sharepoint Designer updating the forms for the underlying content types but when I hovered over the entries the link was still the default and when I clicked on the entry no query string was passed.

How can I get my task list to point to the custom display form without using Javascript? It seems like something that should be fairly easy to do.